# Is health care equal in the emergancy room?

Tags: applied-econometrics, health-economics

How does financial status dictate the level of care differ? Where can you find the best healthcare income to medical service rendered?

I understand that health care differs depending on a geographical location worldwide. Base it one a model with the largest of cities.

Comment: Typically, there are two kinds of heath facilities: public, where you don't need to pay for the services; and private, where you have to pay. Consequently, there are three different kinds of health systems: one, you only have public health facilities; two, you only have private health facilities; and three, you have both. There is a different answer for each kind of system.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just flagging this question for closing as "unclear what you are asking" (which I did), I will also provide an answer to show why this is so, in the hope that the OP will rework their question.

First, there are two totally different questions here. The one is in the title:

> "Is healthcare equal in the emergency room?"

Ignoring the sensationalist flavor of the wording, this is "too broad" a question, because, even as the OP themselves acknowledge, the answer may differ from country to country, depending on the healthcare system and the laws of the country.

Then, there is the second (apparent) question:

> "Depending on your financial status does the level of care differ in a
>   hospital where if you don't pay you die?"

But this is not really a question, because it is already answered by itself: if we start by the premise that we are in a hospital where "if we don't pay we die", then it follows that the level of care we receive will depend on our financial status and our ability to pay. So nothing to answer here.

Comment: It maybe unethical and contradictory to answer if you are unsure. When you down vote, answer and close that locks me into a bad question that I cannot get out of eventually enough of these will result in a system question ban. +1 from me because you did make an effort but  this does not answer my question.

Comment: @Muze Thank you for the upvote, but I did not make an effort to answer your question, I made an effort to show that a) your title question is too broad to be answered ni any useful way and b) that your inside-text question is already answered by itself. And I suggested that you should rework your post, narrowing and making more specific what you ask.